# Puppeteer.Iteration elementHandle array issue

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer

Help me please to achieve the expected result.
I am going to fill each input field on the page with a text: '123'.

```
let inputList = await page.$$('.form input');
inputList.map(async item => {
   await item.type('123');
});
```

Expected Result - 123 in each field.

Actual Result - 112233 on the last input field.

[page.$$(selector) API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1)

Comment: You probably don't want the `item.type` calls to run in parallel, so don't use `map` but a `for … of` loop where `await` stops the iteration.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! `for ... of` works for my case :-)

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't have been using `map` anyway as you didn't want to produce a new array.

Comment: @Bergi OK! Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

In a general sense, you are trying to iterate over an array and perform an asynchronous action on each item in the array. You can accomplish that several ways, the `for ... of` loop is one way. If you don't want to loop but instead want to iterate you can do it this way:

```
await inputList.reduce(async (previousVal, currentVal) => {
    await previousVal; // wait for the promise returned by the previous asynchronous call
    return currentVal.type('123'); // call the next elementHandle in the array
}, Promise.resolve()); // the initial value that is passed to the callback function
```